# How to re-read pulseaudio client configuration without rebooting?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, configuration

I use to modify from time to time the configuration of /etc/pulseaudio/client.conf for commmenting or not that option:
default-server = 192.168.0.10

That server is another Ubuntu and is connected to a hi-fi sound system. Pulse audio is configured on it to receive streams.

Why do I use this? I know that we can use the sound applet to choose the output, including a remote pulse audio server, but it doesn't work well neither with flash or VLC (the sound is chopped). So the only reliable way is to configure the pulseaudio client to use directly the remote pulseaudio server without using my local pulseaudio as a proxy.

**My question:** after enabling or disabling the option *default-server*, the only way to make it applied I found is rebooting the computer ... I also tried:

- killing/starting the local pulseaudio with : `pulseaudio -k ; pulseaudio -D`
- restarting the pulseaudio service : `/etc/init.d/pulseaudio restart`
- both
- close the Unity session and reopen it

None of this is working except rebooting.

Is someone have an idea to apply it without rebooting?

Answer (score 3):

- In the case Pulseaudio is in system mode, you need to be root to restart it, so use "sudo" before your commands or run them in a root terminal:   `sudo su -`
- You can try  additionally to your commands:

  > sudo alsa force-reload

as Pulseaudio  is based on the underlaying Alsa .

Comment: sudo is not the problem. I know I have to use it to modify the state of services. And restart it doesn't read the configuration. But you say "in the case Pulseaudio is in system mode". What does it means?

Comment: pulseaudio is then run as root, i have read (but not tested)  that it works better if you have clicks than using normal  mode, even it realtime is ok for normal user.   in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf    change: system-instance = yes